# Convert Date datatype in oracle to UTC format using oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, utc

I have a date column in this format "03-FEB-16" in a database table.
I want to query the database to get UTC format equivalent of that date value:

This is the UTC format I am looking for
"2015-12-17T14:30:33Z"

Comment: What is the datatype of the column?

Comment: I used "SELECT cast(sentdate as timestamp) at time zone 'UTC' from table_name where id=22110626738" and got this output "03-FEB-16 04.24.31.000000000 PM UTC", however this is not what I want. I wanted "2015-12-17T14:30:33Z"

Comment: That was not my question. I asked "What is the datatype of the column? "

Comment: My apologies, I put the comment in the wrong place. The datatype is DATE.

Comment: OK, and what is the time zone of these date values?

Comment: So one of the value is "2016-02-04T21:13:00Z" (UTC +00 )and the other value that I am getting from the database is "04-FEB-16 09.12.41.000000 PM UTC ". They are both java strings. Now I am looking for a easy way to assert that these both are the same value in java. The later one is in oracle timestamp format.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(cast(SYSDATE as timestamp) at time zone 'UTC', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"') FROM DUAL
```

Change SYSDATE to say SYSDATE-150 to test different times of the year

Answer (score 0):

I think I found my answer but Please feel free to post alternative ways to do it.

The following query did the trick:

```
select to_char(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD')||'T'||to_char(sysdate,'HH24:MI:SS')||'Z' from dual
```

Comment: You can write `select to_char(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"') from dual`. However, this is only correct if your database server OS runs on UTC time zone.

Comment: Based on the information in your comments, your solution is correct.